# Angular2 - How to Do Child-Component-Only Enforcement?

Tags: angular

In Angular2, suppose that I have two components, a list and a list item. I want list item to ONLY be placeable inside a list:

```
<my-list>
    <my-list-item>Foo</my-list-item>
</my-list>
```

Is there a way to enforce this in the TypeScript?

Comment: you mean to say `my-list-item` directive should be only work when it is wrapped with `my-list`?

Comment: Yes. my-list-item should only be able to exist in my-list

Comment: How is TypeScript related to that? If you want `my-list-item` to be inside only of `my-list`, don't write it anywhere else.

Comment: Perhaps he meant to say that he wants the solution in TS and not in JS. But how can we know? `Seen 8 hours ago`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `my-list-item` component do this

and `my-list-item` will not render if it's not inside `my-list`

```ts
import {Component, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-list-item',
  template: '<div *ngIf="insideMyList"> <ng-content></ng-content> </div>'
})
export class MyListItem{
  public insideMyList: boolean = false;

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    if(elementRef['internalElement'].parent.nativeElement.localName == 'my-list')
     { 
        //do other stuff here
        this.insideMyList = true;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: what if `my-list` element is there in parent, but it is parent of parent?

Comment: then instead of checking just immediate parent run a loop for `parent of parent of parent` until parent becomes `my-list` or `undefined` or `body`